# What's the difference between => and :

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the difference between => and : for hash keys in Ruby?

```
  delegate :sum, to: :CONSTANT_ARRAY


  delegate :sum, :to => :CONSTANT_ARRAY
```

Why would one be better than another?

Answer (score 4):

`=>` is more general than just `:`. With `=>` the key can be any data type, whereas using `:` forces the key to be a symbol.

For example:

```
{ a: 1 }
# => {:a=>1} # The key is the symbol :a

{ 'a' => 1 }
# => {"a"=>1} # The key is the string "a"

{ "a": 1 }
# => SyntaxError
```

> Why would one be better than another?

If your keys are symbols then you may find the `:` syntax to be clearer and less cluttered. It is also immediately recognizable to those who are familiar with the JSON data format (though technically the key must be a string surrounded by double-quotes (") according to [the standard](http://json.org/) to be valid JSON syntax, but the non-quoted keys are recognized in many languages including JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference.

It depends on your preference.

`delegate :sum, to: :CONSTANT_ARRAY` is the Ruby 1.9 and after syntax.

`delegate :sum, :to => :CONSTANT_ARRAY` is the Ruby 1.8 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in this case, there's no difference.

The Hash-Rocket `=>` is the old style, probably borrowed from perl, while the colon syntax is the newer, ruby 1.9 style of writing hashes.

The latter is more directed towards json-notation and therefore might be easier to read if one is more familiar with it.

Comment: Wrong. `$set: { 'a.b': 'c' }` is a syntax error but `:$set => { :'a.b' => 'c' }` is fine (and fairly common if you work with MongoDB).

Comment: If you look at the given example in the original post, there is no difference.

Comment: But to say "there's no difference" is still incorrect, that statement should be qualified at the very least. To refer to them as *new* and *old* styles is also incorrect. Even to say that `a: 'b'` is *json-notation* is incorrect since JSON requires that keys be quoted, referring to it as JavaScript-notation would be more accurate.

Comment: Ok, let me say it differently and edit my post accordingly.